# Select 2nd <li> element in a picklist Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver, picklist

I'm having a doozy running into different errors. The goal is set a picklist option so that a report page with various stats updates. The picklist is to choose months and years and whenever I want this report it's for the previous month so the option i always want is the previous months which ends up being li#2.

So I have the following

```
ReportPeriodInput = DriverTransactionSummary.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[2]')
```

If i do something like

```
ReportPeriodInput.click()
```

I get the following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

If I alter how I do it and add get_attribute('innerHTML)

```
ReportPeriodInput = DriverTransactionSummary.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[2]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
ReportPeriodInput.click()
```

I get the following error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'

What is the correct way to select this element and have it be the new value in the picklist? See below for the HTML page details

```
<div id="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_Windows7 RadComboBoxWithLabel" style="white-space:normal;">
<label for="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_Input" class="rcbLabel">Period:</label>
<table summary="combobox" border="0" style="border-width:0;border-collapse:collapse;width:250px">
    <tr class="rcbReadOnly">
        <td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;"><input name="dnn$ctr1001$VolumeByMonthCS$rcbPeriod" type="text" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" id="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_Input" value="(12)December - 2017" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        <td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight"><a id="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="rcbSlide" style="z-index:6000;display:none;">
    <div id="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Windows7 ">
        <div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth">
            <ul class="rcbList">
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2017</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2017</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2017</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2017</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2017</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2017</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2017</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2017</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2017</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2017</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2017</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2017</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2016</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2016</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2016</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2016</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2016</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2016</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2016</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2016</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2016</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2016</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2016</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2016</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2015</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2015</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2015</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2015</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2015</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2015</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2015</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2015</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2015</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2015</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2015</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2015</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2014</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2014</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2014</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2014</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2014</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2014</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2014</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2014</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2014</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2014</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2014</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2014</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2013</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2013</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2013</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2013</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2013</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2013</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2013</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2013</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2013</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2013</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2013</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2013</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2012</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2012</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2012</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2012</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2012</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2012</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2012</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2012</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2012</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2012</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2012</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2012</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2011</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2011</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2011</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2011</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2011</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2011</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2011</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2011</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2011</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2011</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2011</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2011</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2010</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2010</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2010</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2010</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2010</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2010</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2010</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2010</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2010</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2010</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2010</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2010</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2009</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2009</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2009</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2009</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2009</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2009</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2009</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2009</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2009</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2009</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2009</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2009</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2008</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2008</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2008</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2008</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2008</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2008</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2008</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2008</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2008</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2008</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2008</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2008</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2007</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2007</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2007</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2007</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2007</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2007</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2007</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2007</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2007</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2007</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2007</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2007</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2006</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2006</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2006</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2006</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2006</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2006</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2006</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2006</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2006</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2006</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2006</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2006</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2005</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2005</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2005</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2005</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2005</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2005</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2005</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2005</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2005</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2005</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2005</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2005</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(12)December - 2004</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(11)November - 2004</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(10)October - 2004</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(09)September - 2004</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(08)August - 2004</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(07)July - 2004</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(06)June - 2004</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(05)May - 2004</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(04)April - 2004</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(03)March - 2004</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(02)February - 2004</li>
                <li class="rcbItem">(01)January - 2004</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input id="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_ClientState" name="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_ClientState" type="hidden" />
```

And an image of what that looks like:

[image]

Comment: Your second instance of `ReportPeriodInput` is returning a string of the attribute you selected. Thats why that error is occurring. So don't look into that. Go back to your first error as that is closer to what you want. If it is not visible maybe you should put a `wait` before you try and click it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on others help the easiest (may not be the best) way to do it was to make sure to click on the picklist field itself, then I was able to have it find element[2].

```
ReportPeriodClick = DriverTransactionSummary.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_Input"]').click()
ReportPeriodClick2 = DriverTransactionSummary.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[2]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with python but knowing how it works in other languages you should be able to just get a list of elements using `.find_elements_by_css_selector()` and then clicking on the second element in the list.

```
options = DriverTransactionSummary.find_elements_by_css_selector(".rcbItem")
options[1].click();
```

Of course, you would need to click on the dropdown menu first in order to click on the second `li` element in the menu. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah like tehbeardedone says, make sure that you first click on the menu dropdown arrow to make that div.rcbSlide actually visible (note that the style above is display:none)

Comment: Thanks guys, I was able to figure it out based on your suggestions. So unfortunately doing it exactly like you said tehbearedone led me to another error, however I made sure to click onto the picklist to display the values, then i was able to click on the 2nd element.

ReportPeriodClick = DriverTransactionSummary.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_Input"]').click()
    ReportPeriodClick2 = DriverTransactionSummary.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[2]').click()

Answer (score 0):

Let us analyze first what happened with your code trials.

- You have identified an `WebElement` and tried to invoke `click()` as follows :

  ```
  ReportPeriodInput = DriverTransactionSummary.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dnn_ctr1001_VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[2]')
  ReportPeriodInput.click()
  ```

  But this `<li>` is an look alike of `option` within the `DropDown`. Hence you see :

  ```
  selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  ```
- Next you have extracted the `innerHTML` of the above `WebElement` which returns a `String` and tried to invoke `click()` on it. `click()` method is defined for `WebElement`. As `String` Class objects have no `click()` method associated you see the error :

  ```
  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'
  ```

### Solution :

To click on the **`DropDown`** and select the option **`(11)November - 2017`** you have to :

- Identify the **`Dropdown`** `WebElement` and click on it as follows :

  ```
  ReportPeriodInput = DriverTransactionSummary.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Windows7' and contains(@id,'VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_DropDown')]")
  ReportPeriodInput.click()
  ```
- Next you need to click the intended `option` from the **`Dropdown`** as follows :

  ```
  ReportPeriodInputOption = DriverTransactionSummary.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Windows7' and contains(@id,'VolumeByMonthCS_rcbPeriod_DropDown')]/div/ul/li[@class='rcbItem' and contains(.,'November - 2017')]")
  ReportPeriodInputOption.click()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that you have given class to each **li**, the best way to select the second **li** or say a particular child is using **css_selector** method.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul .rcbItem:nth-child(2)").click()
```

The above code will select `(11)November - 2017`